# I can't install a package using the anaconda prompt

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, python-packaging

I want to install a package in Python.
What I do is I save the package folder in:

C:\Users\Zohreh\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages>

Then I chance the directory in anaconda prompt to thi directory and then I type:

C:\Users\Zohreh\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages>pip install nanotrappy

But I got this error:
**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nanotrappy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for nanotrappy**

Based on many tutorials it should work, But it doesn't

Comment: Go into the directory and run `pip install .`

Comment: `conda install nanotrappy`

Comment: @sahasrara62 That wont work, it is not a package that is on conda or pip.

Comment: You should not write anything in the `site-packages` directory yourself. I would recommend you to save (or git-clone) the project's source code directory somewhere else.

Comment: [PyPi](https://pypi.org/search/?q=nanotrappy) shows no known package: then it's likely not installable with `pip install nanotrappy`, unless you've configured Pip to (also) pick up another package database.

Comment: Are you sure this library is compatible with (ana)conda?